# want to know if the image is not available at url using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

in my application i am downloading an image from url from webservice using SDWebImage Library. I have nothing problem with this code

```
[imgQuestionContainer sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"] placeholderImage:@"abc.png" options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];
```

with above code i have successfully load the image in imageview...

But my problem is that if i have url for the image but image is not available at that particular path of url. So, how to know that image is not available so i can load next data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what exactly i wanted.

```
[imgQuestionContainer sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[arrOfLoadedPuzzel objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"puzzle_question"]]
                  placeholderImage:nil
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
                        {
                            if(error)
                            {
                                 // image is not available
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 // image is available
                            }
                       }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                        success:^(UIImage *image) {
                                       if(image){

                                       }else{

                                            }
}
                        failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                      }];
];
```